# Alternate for Indirect used with Sumifs?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010

I am using the formula to ~300 cells which takes the address dynamically using INDIRECT function, but it is slowing down the calculation time.

please suggest me an alternative method to make the calculation faster.

I have done basics as it has macro with screen updating= false and calculation=xlmanual.

`=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$L:$L,Sheet1!$I:$I,Bookings_QTD!$F51,Sheet1!$B:$B,Bookings_QTD!I$2,INDIRECT($I$8),$K$8,Sheet1!$C:$C,$M$8)/1000000`

here cell $I$8 is dynamic where values will varies based eg:-Sheet5!$A:$A, Sheet5!$B:$B...

`$I$8=Sheet5!$E:$E`

I need to use it for many cells ~400+ with other criterias in future.

kindly suugest me better formula or method which will decrease the calculation time.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you mean a formula that will decrease the calculation time (not increase)? :) Could you explain how you change the `I8` content? Based on what?

Comment: Since you have $I$8 locked, I assume that all 300 cells are searching in the same range? If so, have you considered making a Named Ranged so that the indirect is only calculated 1 time, as opposed to 300?

Comment: @Ioannis- Based on dropdown change values will change in cell `I8`. @Aaron - I have tried with Named Range too, still no major impact on calculation time

Answer (score 1):

`INDIRECT()` will be slow for many sheets as it is a Volatile function. i.e. every time there is a change in **any cell** in the workbook, it will get triggered.

If your cell values are relatively static. i.e. if you are indirectly referring to cell "B6" and you expect the content of `B6` to remain the same and only expect the input of your function to change, say from "B6" to "Z8", you can use the following code:

```
Function MyIndirect(RangeStr as String) as Variant
    MyIndirect = ActiveSheet.Range("RangeStr").Value
End Function
```

This should work. And should you need to 'refresh' this value, simply run an `Application.Calculation` (i.e. press `Ctrl-Alt-F9`)